# How do I convert a 3*1 vector into a 2*2 lower triangular matrix in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have created a network in pytorch, whose output is `B*N*H*W`. I want that `N` is equal to 3 and then convert the output into a 2*2 lower trangular matrix with a upper zero in the 2nd demension. There may be two ways to achieve that.

```
    class Net(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, in_ch=3, out_ch=N):
        super().__init__():
            self.net = nn.Sequatial([...])
        def forward(self, x):
            return self.net(x)
```

First, let the network output be `B*4*H*W`, and then mutiple a mask of `[1,0,1,1]` in the 2nd dimension to make one channel to be zero. This way can get a 2*2 lower trangular matrix with a upper zero, while I don't know if there will be information lost. And I don't know how to check the loss of information while training.

```
    class Net(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, in_ch=3, out_ch=4):
        super().__init__():
            self.net = nn.Sequatial([...])
            self.mask = torch.FloatTensor([1.,0.,1.,1.]).cuda()
        def forward(self, x):
            return torch.einsum('abij,b->abij', self.net(x), self.mask)
```

Second, I think that the direct solution is to output a `B*3*H*W` tensor and convert the 2nd dimension into a 2*2 lower trangular matrix with a upper zero. But I don't have an effictive approach to implementing this. The transform operation in 2nd dimension may be like:

```
    array[2.3, 5.1, 6.3]  -->  array[[2.3, 0.],
                                     [5.1, 6.3]]
```

There are still two questions. How to convert the 2nd dimension of `B*3*H*W` to a tensor of shape `B*2*2*H*W` and if the first method will make the information lost while training.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

You can easily calculate `N` from `len(a)` as `N*(N+1)/2 = len(a) => N`

Here is the `numpy` version:

```
a = np.array([2.3, 5.1, 6.3])  
N = 2

c = np.zeros((N, N))
c[np.tril_indices(N)] = a
```

Output:

```
c
>array([[2.3, 0. ],
       [5.1, 6.3]])
```

Here is the pytorch version:

```
a = torch.tensor([2.3, 5.1, 6.3])
c = torch.zeros(N, N)
c[torch.tril_indices(N, N, offset=0).tolist()] = a
c
```

Output:

```
tensor([[2.3000, 0.0000],
        [5.1000, 6.3000]])
```

Comment: Thanks! The lower trangular matrix can be got by this way. But I worry about the time cost of converting from numpy.array to torch.tensor, which I could test by myself, and is there an equal API in pytorch. Otherwise, whether this operation as you said will cause problems while loss backward.

Comment: There should be equivalents in pytorch. I update my answer now to work directly with torch tensors

Comment: I updated the solution for pytorch version

Comment: Thanks for that! I will try this approach in my code.